# jquery to angularjs: collapse panel and change button image

Tags: angularjs

I am in the process of learning AngularJS (I've taken the Udemy course - AngularJS KickStart, read a few books including Instant AngularJS Starter and Mastering Web Application Development with AngularJS and surfed the net for this) and I can't figure out how to change the button image when using Angular's show/hide.

Here is what I have using jQuery --

HTML:

```
<div id="landing_header_bar" data-tbl="tblProjects" class="clr-gold">
    <img class="btnToggleLanding" src="../Images/close_btn.png" alt="Close This">
    <h3 class="divider_title inlined">Projects</h3>
</div>
<table id="tblProjects" class="tblLanding">
          <tr class="landing_header_row">
            <th>Priority</th>
            <th>Case ID</th>
            <th>Project Description</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Site</th>
            <th>Requestor</th>
            <th>Assigned To</th>
            <th>Due Date</th>
          </tr>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="landing_data_row">
              <td><div class='sprite indicRed centered'></div></td>
              <td style="text-align:center;">001</td>
              <td><a href="EditProject.html">New case 2</a></td>
              <td>In Progress</td>
              <td>Brother USA</td>
              <td>Smith, William J.</td>
              <td>Smith, William J.</td>
              <td>09/13/2013</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="landing_data_row">
              <td><div class='sprite indicRed centered'></div></td>
              <td style="text-align:center;">010</td>
              <td><a href="EditProject.html">We Must have a new task system</a></td>
              <td>Waiting</td>
              <td>IPD Home</td>
              <td>Sawyer, Benji</td>
              <td>Sawyer, Benji</td>
              <td>09/16/2013</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="landing_data_row">
              <td><div class='sprite indicRed centered'></div></td>
              <td style="text-align:center;">014</td>
              <td><a href="EditProject.html">amet</a></td>
              <td>Open</td>
              <td>HAD</td>
              <td>Sawyer, Benji</td>
              <td>Sawyer, Benji</td>
              <td>09/18/2013</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).on('click', '.btnToggleLanding', function(e) {
                // alert('clicked');
                var $this = $(this);

                var tbl = $this.parent().data('tbl');
                $('#' + tbl).slideToggle('slow', function() {
                    var $img = $this.attr('src');
                    if ($img.indexOf('open') > -1) {
                        $this.attr('src', '../Images/close_btn.png');
                    } else {
                        $this.attr('src', '../Images/open_btn.png');
                    } // end if
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here's my AngularJS attempt:

```
<div id="landing_header_bar" data-tbl="tblProjects" class="clr-gold">
                <img class="btnToggleLanding" src="../Images/close_btn.png" alt="Close This" ng-model="collapsed" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed">
                <h3 class="divider_title inlined">Projects</h3>
            </div>
            <table id="tblProjects" class="tblLanding" ng-hide="collapsed">
              <tr class="landing_header_row">
                <th>Priority</th>
                <th>Case ID</th>
                <th>Project Description</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Site</th>
                <th>Requestor</th>
                <th>Assigned To</th>
                <th>Due Date</th>
              </tr>
              <tbody>
                <tr class="landing_data_row">
                  <td><div class='sprite indicRed centered'></div></td>
                  <td style="text-align:center;">001</td>
                  <td><a href="EditProject.html">New case 2</a></td>
                  <td>In Progress</td>
                  <td>Brother USA</td>
                  <td>Smith, William J.</td>
                  <td>Smith, William J.</td>
                  <td>09/13/2013</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="landing_data_row">
                  <td><div class='sprite indicRed centered'></div></td>
                  <td style="text-align:center;">010</td>
                  <td><a href="EditProject.html">We Must have a new task system</a></td>
                  <td>Waiting</td>
                  <td>IPD Home</td>
                  <td>Sawyer, Benji</td>
                  <td>Sawyer, Benji</td>
                  <td>09/16/2013</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="landing_data_row">
                  <td><div class='sprite indicRed centered'></div></td>
                  <td style="text-align:center;">014</td>
                  <td><a href="EditProject.html">amet</a></td>
                  <td>Open</td>
                  <td>HAD</td>
                  <td>Sawyer, Benji</td>
                  <td>Sawyer, Benji</td>
                  <td>09/18/2013</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

The hide/show works perfectly but I can't figure out how to change the image with AngularJS. Can someone point me to the right resource or show me how I can swap out the image like I do in the jQuery version??

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: To change the image `src` attribute like the equivalent jQuery you have, you can make use of `ng-src` and have the link itself update based on a `$watch`. Simple example like so: http://jsfiddle.net/AkB9D/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toggle two images, rather than switching the source of one:

```
<img alt="Close This"
  ng-click="collapsed = true" 
  ng-show="collapsed == false" />
<img alt="Open This" 
  ng-click="collapsed = false" 
  ng-show="collapsed == true" />
```

Here is a demo:  http://plnkr.co/uL4UudyJndzyosuh76F7

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-show and ng-hide respectively.

```
<img alt="Close This" ng-click="collapsed = true" ng-hide="collapsed" />
<img alt="Open This" ng-click="collapsed = false" ng-show="collapsed" />
```